Countif count Sunday to Friday correctly until it reach Saturday in google sheets
I have 14 dates which only 1 fall on a Saturday. I like to count that Saturday and use it in another formula.
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF((WEEKDAY(D5:D31,1)),"=7"))
However, the answers I get from the formula is 14 and not 1.
True holiday counter

You can try
=arrayformula(countif(MAP(tocol(B5:B,1),LAMBDA(a,weekday(a))),"=7"))

@Kreezh, thank you it work perfectly.


A blank cell is taken for value 0; you can test it by pointing at an empty cell say A1 and enter this formula in B1 =value(A1)
which comes out as 0

at the same time, number 0 equates to the date Sat, 30 December 1899 when represented in date-format style & your countif formula is counting the one visible saturday + 13 blank cells which are equating to saturday in the backend

a short article on why 0 = 30-dec-1899 & an excerpt is pasted below:



So when Microsoft program designers thought of choosing a date for the
start of their day numbering system, they thought of the first day of
the 20th century, which was 1 January 1900. But this was to be day 1,
not day zero. That made day zero 31st December 1899.
Whether they overlooked the fact that the year 1900 is not a leap year
or whether they deliberately ignored the complication, I do not know,
but their algorithm for working out the day number from the date
assumes the year 1900 was a leap year. It was not. Thus all day
numbers prior to 1 March 1900 are incorrect by one day. This makes the
base date (day zero) 30th rather than 31st December 1899. This explains why 30th December 1899 is the base date for Microsoft Works database and spreadsheet programs.



Thank you the explanation expanded my understanding and allow me to learn more.
